# Fullscreen masonry gallery without scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

I have the following script: https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/pvamyK

```js
function getRandomSize(min, max) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var allImages = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  var width = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  var height = getRandomSize(200, 400);
  allImages += '<img src="https://placekitten.com/' + width + '/' + height + '" alt="pretty kitty">';
}

$('#photos').append(allImages);
```

```css
#photos {
  /* Prevent vertical gaps */
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-column-count: 5;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
  -moz-column-count: 5;
  -moz-column-gap: 0px;
  column-count: 5;
  column-gap: 0px;
}

#photos img {
  /* Just in case there are inline attributes */
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #photos {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
  }
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="photos"></section>
```

I would like to modify this so the total grid height always equals `100vh`

Do you think its possible?

Images can of course resize in order to fit the `100vh`. The grid should not be responsive, by which I mean the number of columns can stay the same, while images shrink. The number of columns does not really matter.

Goal is to fit all images on one `viewport` without scrollbars

Comment: Here is a codedump, please update it to meet these requirements?